# Asking for my old job back

Tags: professionalism, termination

I was terminated by a medical device company for falsifying test records on a production line. I did it so I could make my daily quota. I was under pressure and didn't openly discuss this with my supervisor. I've been unemployed for four months now. My performance was otherwise satisfactory. Would it be worth a shot at asking for my old job back, or did I betray their trust in me?

Comment: It's always worth a shot, what do you have to lose? If i was the employer you would not be hired back as what you did was a definite betrayal and depending on what you were testing could have lead to big issues. But some people are more forgiving so give it a shot.

Answer (score 15):

I want you to understand the severity of what you did. **Medical devices with falsified test records could be defective and thus kill/injure people.** The company has a responsibility make sure their devices don't kill/injure people. I would imagine you also cost them a lot of money, as they would likely have notified the current owners of these devices that they needed to be reinspected so as to avoid criminal charges if the device killed or injured people due to a known falsified record. There is no possible way that you are getting rehired.

Comment: Normally I would suggest that this answer is a little bit absolute and harsh. But you're absolutely correct. Some things transcend the normal cordiality one would expect. I would add that for them to rehire him could cause significant liability for rehiring someone who they know falsifies records.

Comment: downvoted because although probably an accurate statement of fact, this is not really an answer to the OP's question.

Comment: This is spot on.  To the general question, you might be able to get your job back if you show contrition, but for this particular case, absolutely not.  Just wait until someone is impacted by a faulty device that OP passed and the company has to go to court.

Comment: Actually he did answer it. OP asked if it would be worth a shot or did he betray trust. "There's no possible way that you are getting rehired" is that answer and he explains exactly how that trust was betrayed and why.  It's a good answer, IMHO

Comment: @ChristopherEstep good point, DV removed.

Comment: @ChristopherEstep, for future reference, I am a she not a he.

Comment: @HLGEM Sorry about that.  :)

Answer (score 6):

You could try, but don't be surprised if you get a hard "No" from them.

You broke their trust in you.  That's one of the worst things you could do.  If they DO give you a second chance, you have a mountain to climb just to get back to where you were.

Next time, talk to your supervisor about your concerns and accept the repercussions of not meeting your quota.